# How can I resend messages from dead letter queue using Particular ServiceInsight?

Tags: azureservicebus, dead-letter, serviceinsight

We are implementing ServiceInsight as our Azure ServiceBus monitoring system.
I know that it's possible to resend messages from the error queue, but is it possible to resend messages that are on the dead letter queue?

Answer (score 1):

ServiceInsight is a tool for NServiceBus, if you work with Azure ServiceBus you need to look into [ServiceBus Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2014/05/21/service-bus-explorer-2-3-and-2-1-improved-version-now-available.aspx) instead.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: ServiceInsight, I believe, also works with Azure ServiceBus and you can retry failed messages from the error queue.  ServiceBusExplorer allows you to retry a single message from the dead letter queue but it doesn't appear to allow you to retry in bulk, which is what we're looking for.